# PHP jQuery load data into bootstrap modal box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I need to load dynamic data into bootstrap modal box.

JS:

```
$(function() {

    $('.push').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '../controller/booksdetails.php', // in here you should put your query 
            data: 'cmid=' + id, // here you pass your id via ajax .
            // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
            success: function(r) {
                // now you can show output in your modal 
                $('#cm').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: false
                    }) // put your modal id 
                $('.something').show().html(r);
            }
        });


    });

});
```

PHP file :

```
if(isset($_POST['cmid'])){
$DB =  mysqli::f("SELECT * FROM " . BOOKS . " WHERE id = ?",filter_var($_POST['cmid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
print_r($DB);
}
```

and **print** data into modalbox `div` with `class="something"`. this method true worked and **print** all php array result.

now I need to work with php array *aftar* load data into modalbox(work with php class, secure data, ....). I mean is: **load** php data into modalbox (ie : `json`) **not print** result into modalbox.

how do can I generate this?

Answer (score -1):

Hi man here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/kwh2n00v/1/

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="insert">
  insert data
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#insert').on('click', function (){
    // This should be on your AJAX Success
    var data="some dynamic data";
    $('.modal-body').html(data);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    //--------------------------------------
})
```

I hope this helps...
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/kwh2n00v/1/

Comment: Your method likely to my method!!! in your method u print all result into modal box!! I don't need to this.

Comment: can you be more specific with the question?